# Why am I getting InvalidUseOfMatchersException here?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am getting following error in my test case:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Exception occured :
        org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
        Invalid use of argument matchers!
        2 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
```

This is my piece of code:

```
Mockito.when(mockHelloPeristenceImpl.retrieveHellorequest(Mockito.anyLong()))
              .thenReturn(Mockito.any(Hellorequest.class));
```

I tried all option suggested in the internet for this issue, nothing worked.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return a `Matcher` in the way you're doing it. You have to specify *the actual object* you're returning. Either do something like:

```
Mockito.when(mockHelloPeristenceImpl.retrieveHellorequest(Mockito.anyLong()))
       .thenReturn(Mockito.mock(Hellorequest.class));
```

Or, give it an answering strategy, e.g.

```
Mockito.when(mockHelloPeristenceImpl.retrieveHellorequest(Mockito.anyLong()))
       .then(Mockito.RETURNS_MOCKS);
```

---

As an aside, your code can be much shorter by using:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
```

Then your test statement will be, simply:

```
when(mockHelloPeristenceImpl.retrieveHellorequest(anyLong()))
          .then(RETURNS_MOCKS);
```